# Upload file through PHP webpage

Tags: php, file, upload

I trying to create an apache2 webpage that allows user upload `nifti(.nii, .nii.gz)` files.

I tried two different ways:

1. On WSL Ubuntu 18.04, `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)` returns nothing. It totally fails.
2. On XAMPP, the page can take files such as PDF, JPG .etc, but not `.nii`, `.exe` (I checked `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];` is empty)

HTML:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select the file to upload: 
    <input type="file" name="file"> 
    <input class="" type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$target_dir = "/home/user/public_html/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$file_tmp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    echo "<br>";
} else {
    $moving = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $target_file);
    echo $moving;
    echo "here <br>";
    if ($moving) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been 
 uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

1. Did someone upload a file successfully on a WSL apache2?
2. Why I can't upload files like `.nii`, `.nii.gz`, and `.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, After a few hours trying, I found out why I cannot upload ".nii", and ".nii.gz". but I have new questions.

Even if I have already set:

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
Post_max_size = 500M
```

The page still cannot take files greater than 8M, I saw that on the php error.log.

The .gz file is smaller than 8M, but the extracted file is greater than 8M, so it cannot be uploaded.

Does someone know why my "php.ini" setting is not working?